# log-log and log-lin regression analysis

Tags: regression, logarithm

May I ask if it is possible to combine transformed (ln) independent variables with those with no transformation in a single model?

For example:
log Y = a + B1 ln X1 + B2 X2 + B3 ln X3 + u

Thank you so much for your help. This online class situation is making it difficult for research students like me.

Comment: I think you mean the log of the independent variable, eg, ln(x1), and want an estimate of its coefficient, b, so the expression you might need is b ln(x1), as a sample.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But can I use a combination of log and no transformation in the regressors?

Comment: Yes. Sure.  Why not?

Answer (score 2):

This approach *can* make sense, but I probably wouldn't throw it into a regression arbitrarily in hopes that it would happen to work well. To explain I'm going to reduce it to a simpler case with only one input variable:

$$
\log(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(X) + \beta_2 X + \epsilon
$$

- **Disadvantages**/reasons not to do this: in general $X$ and $\log(X)$ will be strongly correlated with each other: the narrower the range of $X$, the stronger the (linear) correlation will be. Thus including both variables in the model might weaken your ability to see the influence of either one.
- **Advantages**: if we exponentiate both sides we get

$$
\begin{split}
Y & = \exp(\beta_0) \cdot X^{\beta_1} \cdot \exp(\beta_2 X)  \cdot \exp(\epsilon) \\
  & = c_0 X^{\beta_1} \exp(\beta_2X)\cdot \eta
\end{split}
$$

The functional form for the mean here is the same as that of a Gamma distribution (i.e. $y \propto x^\gamma e^{-x}$); it's a generalization of the *Ricker model* from ecology. The overall conditional response distribution is log-Normal (because the error term $\eta = \exp(\epsilon)$, I'm assuming $\epsilon$ is Normal). In some circumstances you might want to model a set of nonlinear curves that had this shape (for negative values of $\beta_2$ and positive values of $\beta_1$, the resulting curve is generally unimodal).

Comment: Could you clarify the sense in which you refer to "a Gamma distribution"? Even when you view $X$ as a random variable, the effect of multiplication by the (presumably) independent $\eta=\exp(\varepsilon)$ would usually ensure $Y$ does not have a Gamma distribution.